# How to use tocify with asciidoctor for a dynamic toc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tableofcontents, asciidoctor, jquery-tocify-js

By default, [asciidoctor](http://asciidoctor.org) creates a static toc. This is very cool but for long documents, it would be nice to if the toc could be somewhat more compact and would highlight where in the document the reader currently is.

At this point, [tocify](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.tocify.js/) comes in. Tocify is a nice Javascript solution exactly to cover this.

Now the question is: how to use tocify with asciidoctor?

Asciidoctor [issue 699](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/699) is relevant here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Enable [docinfo processing](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#docinfo-file) in your asciidoc files, e.g. by passing the following options to asciidoctor:

```
-a toc=left -a docinfo=shared
```

Add a `docinfo.html` file next to your asciidoc files with the following content:

```
<!-- Generate a nice TOC -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tocify/1.9.0/javascripts/jquery.tocify.min.js"></script>
<!-- We do not need the tocify CSS because the asciidoc CSS already provides most of what we neeed -->

<style>
.tocify-header {
    font-style: italic;
}

.tocify-subheader {
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 90%;
}

.tocify ul {
    margin: 0;
 }

.tocify-focus {
    color: #7a2518; 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.tocify-focus > a {
    color: #7a2518; 
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Add a new container for the tocify toc into the existing toc so we can re-use its
        // styling
        $("#toc").append("<div id='generated-toc'></div>");
        $("#generated-toc").tocify({
            extendPage: true,
            context: "#content",
            highlightOnScroll: true,
            hideEffect: "slideUp",
            // Use the IDs that asciidoc already provides so that TOC links and intra-document
            // links are the same. Anything else might confuse users when they create bookmarks.
            hashGenerator: function(text, element) {
                return $(element).attr("id");
            },
            // Smooth scrolling doesn't work properly if we use the asciidoc IDs
            smoothScroll: false,
            // Set to 'none' to use the tocify classes
            theme: "none",
            // Handle book (may contain h1) and article (only h2 deeper)
            selectors: $( "#content" ).has( "h1" ).size() > 0 ? "h1,h2,h3,h4,h5" : "h2,h3,h4,h5",
            ignoreSelector: ".discrete"
        });

        // Switch between static asciidoc toc and dynamic tocify toc based on browser size
        // This is set to match the media selectors in the asciidoc CSS
        // Without this, we keep the dynamic toc even if it is moved from the side to preamble
        // position which will cause odd scrolling behavior
        var handleTocOnResize = function() {
            if ($(document).width() < 768) {
                $("#generated-toc").hide();
                $(".sectlevel0").show();
                $(".sectlevel1").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#generated-toc").show();
                $(".sectlevel0").hide();
                $(".sectlevel1").hide();
            }
        }

        $(window).resize(handleTocOnResize);
        handleTocOnResize();
    });
</script>
```