# From jQuery to vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this chunk of code which is using jQuery and I want it to be a vanilla javascript.

I used self executable function and got rid of the `$`. Well it stops working as soon as I get rid of the first `$` before the anonymous function and rewrite it in vanilla JS...

```js
$(function() {
  $("#toc").append("<div id='generated-toc'></div>");
  $("#generated-toc").tocify({
    extendPage: true,
    context: "#content",
    highlightOnScroll: true,
    hideEffect: "slideUp",
    hashGenerator: function(text, element) {
      return $(element).attr("id");
    },
    smoothScroll: false,
    theme: "none",
    selectors: $("#content").has("h1").size() > 0 ? "h1,h2,h3,h4,h5" : "h2,h3,h4,h5",
    ignoreSelector: ".discrete"
  });

  var handleTocOnResize = function() {
    if ($(document).width() < 768) {
      $("#generated-toc").hide();
      $(".sectlevel0").show();
      $(".sectlevel1").show();
    } else {
      $("#generated-toc").show();
      $(".sectlevel0").hide();
      $(".sectlevel1").hide();
    }
  }

  $(window).resize(handleTocOnResize);
  handleTocOnResize();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So I write it like this...But
for some reason(s) it isn 't working...

```js
(function() {
  document.getElementById("toc").append("<div id='generated-toc'></div>");
  document.getElementById("generated-toc").tocify({
    extendPage: true,
    context: "#content",
    highlightOnScroll: true,
    hideEffect: "slideUp",
    hashGenerator: function(text, element) {
      return element.attr("id");
    },
    smoothScroll: false,
    theme: "none",
    selectors: document.getElementById("content").has("h1").size() > 0 ? "h1,h2,h3,h4,h5" : "h2,h3,h4,h5",
    ignoreSelector: ".discrete"
  });

  var handleTocOnResize = function() {
    if (document.width() < 768) {
      document.getElementsByName("generated-toc").hide();
      document.getElementsByClassName("sectlevel0").show();
      document.getElementsByClassName("sectlevel1").show();
    } else {
      document.getElementById("generated-toc").show();
      document.getElementsByClassName("sectlevel0").hide();
      document.getElementsByClassName("sectlevel1").hide();
    }
  }

  window.resize(handleTocOnResize);
  handleTocOnResize();
})();
```

Comment: Just removing $ does not make it vanilla JS ...

Comment: You are mixing Jquery and Javascript. This will not work the way you have done it.

Comment: Please post the html part of this as well.

Comment: @UsmanMunir This is a fix that is used for asciidoctor's dynamic table of content (toc): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34481638/how-to-use-tocify-with-asciidoctor-for-a-dynamic-toc Where toc is created at compile time.

Comment: @71GA Please give some example HTML I can add in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: I had to downgrade the jQuery to match the tocify

What is the point of rewriting jQuery when you are still dependent on jQuery?

Findings so far without having access to the HTML

1. The jQuery also does not work - *.size  has been removed in jQuery 3.0.* 
   Use the .length property instead. translates to `document.querySelectorAll("#content h1").length` - vanilla does not have `has`
2. Your `(function() {` means you have to add the JS after the document. Instead use `window.addEventListener("load",function() {`
3. append is not vanilla
4. `element.attr` is not vanilla. `element.getAttribute("id")` or just `element.id`
5. `show`/`hide` is not vanilla. You need `classList.toggle("hide")` OR use media queries or set the `hidden` attribute
6. `element.resize` is not vanilla. `window.addEventListener("resize", handleTocOnResize);` is or `element.onresize`
7. getElementsByName is not valid on an ID and would return a node list if the element(s) had name, which is not a valid attribute on a div.
8. `getElementsByClassName`You cannot change classes on a node list - I changed to `querySelector`
9. document.width is not vanilla.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("toc").innerHTML += "<div id='generated-toc'></div>";
  const $genToc = $("#generated-toc"); // seems it MUST be a jQuery object
  $genToc.tocify({
    extendPage: true,
    context: "#content",
    highlightOnScroll: true,
    hideEffect: "slideUp",
    hashGenerator: function(text, element) {
      return element.id;
    },
    smoothScroll: false,
    theme: "none",
    selectors: document.querySelectorAll("#content h1").length > 0 ? "h1,h2,h3,h4,h5" : "h2,h3,h4,h5",
    ignoreSelector: ".discrete"
  });

  var handleTocOnResize = function() {
    // https://gist.github.com/joshcarr/2f861bd37c3d0df40b30
    const w=window,d=document,e=d.documentElement,g=d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],x=w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||g.clientWidth;
    const show = x < 768 // or use media queries
   // $genToc[0].classList.toggle("hide", !show);
    document.querySelector(".sectlevel0").classList.toggle("hide", show);
    document.querySelector(".sectlevel0").classList.toggle("hide", show);
  }

  window.addEventListener("resize", handleTocOnResize);
  handleTocOnResize();
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}


.tocify-header {
    font-style: italic;
}

.tocify-subheader {
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 90%;
}

.tocify ul {
    margin: 0;
 }

.tocify-focus {
    color: #7a2518; 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.tocify-focus > a {
    color: #7a2518; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tocify/1.9.0/javascripts/jquery.tocify.min.js"></script>


<div id="content">
  <h1>Toc</h1>
  <p class="sectlevel0">Level 0</p>
  <p class="sectlevel1">Level 1</p>
</div>
<div id="toc"></div>
```

jQuery test version to see if we can make the original code work

```js
const handleTocOnResize = function() {
  const show = $(document).width() < 768;
  $("#generated-toc").toggle(!show);
  $(".sectlevel0").toggle(show);
  $(".sectlevel1").toggle(show);
};


$(function() {
  $("#toc").append("<div id='generated-toc'></div>");
  $("#generated-toc").tocify({
    extendPage: true,
    context: "#content",
    highlightOnScroll: true,
    hideEffect: "slideUp",
    hashGenerator: function(text, element) {
      return $(element).attr("id");
    },
    smoothScroll: false,
    theme: "none",
    selectors: $("#content h1").length > 0 ? "h1,h2,h3,h4,h5" : "h2,h3,h4,h5",
    ignoreSelector: ".discrete"
  });


  $(window).on("resize", handleTocOnResize);
  handleTocOnResize();
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}

.tocify-header {
  font-style: italic;
}

.tocify-subheader {
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 90%;
}

.tocify ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.tocify-focus {
  color: #7a2518;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.tocify-focus>a {
  color: #7a2518;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tocify/1.9.0/javascripts/jquery.tocify.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
  <h1>Toc</h1>
  <p class="sectlevel0">Level 0</p>
  <p class="sectlevel1">Level 1</p>
</div>
<div id="toc"></div>
```

Comment: [`resize` is vanilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event)

Comment: @KooiInc `element.resize`  is  not valid. It should be `element.onresize` or as I wrote `element.addEventListener("resize")`

Comment: This is nice but I found a better solution! I used tocbot!